# Why does every image I build have its own repository?

Tags: docker

What does "repository" mean to the build process? Why does every image need a repository?

I guess I should take this question up with whoever architect or team made this naming choice but why is there a new "repository" created whenever I build a new image for the same project? I think of repositories a service which stores multiple versions of multiple projects.
I don't see why running 'docker build -t localBind9.v02 .' should result in any kind of repo.
I had a 'actual' docker repository running at some point but to use that I had to deliberately push an image into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to share my opinionated definitions that do not match the "official" definitions...

One stores one or more Docker *images* in a Docker *repository* (or more precisely, this would be known as *repositories* in the official definition), locally. I like to call this "the repository" rather than "repositories" when talking about the list of images that appear locally when I do `docker images` at the command line because "repositories" (plural) sounds confusing from that perspective to a lot of users. I think of the list of Docker images as being more analogous to a Maven repository, rather than some list of individual, separate Git repositories.

This local Docker repository may pull images from a public registry, such as Docker Hub, or a private registry, such as on a private network, for ease of sharing. Additionally, one can push an image to one of these registries.

Each *container* is an instance of the *image* (analogous to an *object* being an instance of a *class*). There is probably someone out there that thinks this definition is grossly incorrect, but it works for me.

Related:

1. [Difference between Docker registry and repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004076/difference-between-docker-registry-and-repository)
2. [What's the Difference Between Docker Images and Containers?](https://aws.amazon.com/compare/the-difference-between-docker-images-and-containers)